# Facebook FQL/Graph API - How to get the real likes and shares for a URl?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been searching via Google and found so many articles about this but now I need to ask some general questions.

I'm trying to get the likes and shares for a URl in Facebook. Please correct if I have misunderstood what a URl is in this context.
I have a URl with special content I want to promote via Facebook. I share it via a special Facebook page I built up for this articles.
Then I share this content of this page with my personal account in different groups. In every article I distribute in different groups the original URl with all its opengraph data is inside. This content is distributed by Facebook with a marker, that I (my name) shared content of a page (page name).

I have tried so many ways to get the shares and likes for this URl I posted via facebokk, but never got the correct values.
When I for example aks the "link_stat" table I get a number like 29 for likes. If I take a look a the content/URl I posted at the page 34 users liked it und the published URl in a group is liked by 59 users. Can you help me what this like from "link_stat" means?

I thought, if facebook users like and share the URl distributed via this way in one or more groups I get all likes and shares for this URl all over Facebook?
Am I wrong?
Thanks für your help!

Regards,
Jens

Comment: _“und the published URl in a group is liked by 59 users”_ – those are most likely not likes on the URL, but on the _post_ that you made to share it.

Comment: OK, that's what I suggested. That means if I want to catch all likes for my "promotion posts" to get the number of users who probably like my URl I have to aks the API for all my post IDs, is this correct?

If this is right it seems to be impossible to get the real number of likes for posts and shares all over facebook where my URl ist mentioned ...